# SharePoint 2010 - IsNotBlank formula

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Read a few threads about this. Maybe my brain is dead today but I can't figure out how to do a not blank formula in a calculated column.

What i want to do is to show an icon in a column IF another column is not blank (ie. contains some information).

In my case, if the Due Date column is populated, I'd like a flag icon to be displayed.

I've used the icons before but never in this type of scenario.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF( ISBLANK([Due Date] , "" , "<IMG SRC=""http://url to your flag icon"">")
```

To get the HTML to work you need to set the datatype of your Calculated Column to **Number**!